# Can you tell if a plant is edible by watching what animals eat it?

Tags: animal-behaviour, plants, edible

If I see a deer munching on a particular plant, is that enough to indicate that it's safe to eat? How about other animals?

Comment: Deer love tobacco, and on a golf course in my home town they were known to snatch cigarettes out of golfers' hands. I would not recommend eating tobacco.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No.

For one, you may not be capable of gathering any worthwhile nutrition. You could eat grass all day and still be hungry.

Secondly, many animals are immune to toxins that are nasty to us. Best example I know of is that goats and many other new world animals can eat poison ivy. But if you try eating it, you're in trouble.

Comment: Another good example is deadly nightshade, or any other plant containing atropine.  Many animals (rabits, cattle, goats) can eat it, but just few leaves or berries are likely to kill you.